# R and Pandas: R equivalent of np.sum and np.reshape

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, reshape

I have two line of code which I want to convert to R from Python:

Can anyone convert the below line of code from python to R:

```
np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=0)
```

&

```
np.reshape(li, [-1, N])
```

li is the list of elements and N is any variable.

Comment: You can add also input/output data, because sometimes R coder cannot run this code...

Comment: np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=0) should result in array([0, 6])

For np.reshape(li, [-1, N]), I am not able to understand how this works and what is being done here. I am currently converting the python code to R and not able to understand this.
li is ['1',2','3,], single dimensional array

Answer (score 3):

Example data in R -

```
mat<-matrix(c(0,5,0,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

This is what it will look like -

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    5    1
```

**1st part**

```
rowSums(mat)
```

Output will look like this -

```
[1] 0 6
```

If this doesn't seem to work as per needs try `colSums` (equivalent to varying `axis` in `numpy`)

**2nd Part**

```
matrix(mat, 1, length(mat))
```

This will flatten the array similar to `np.reshape()`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    5    0    1
```

This is the part where you want to flatten your matrix. `reshape` in `numpy` can be re-written in R by calling the `matrix()` function to re-cast the existing `mat` object

**Note**

This is a pure R implementation (standard libs). There are many other libraries like `rehsape2` that will do it in different ways